# UIWebView track user input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

is there a way to track the user-input to a uiwebview?

In my case the user must fill out several folders in the webpage (Login form). However, the input (strings) should then be handeled by / stored in the app. (App should remember login-info and do login next time automatically)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Implement

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

This [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) . This method gets called whenever your webview is about to make a request. So now when someone clicks a button on your webpage, you will get a call to this method. After you catch this call, you can choose to do whatever you want with it. Like redirect the link through your own servers, or log a request to your server about user activity etc.

Example - here you are trying to intercept any links clicked on your webpage & pass it through `myMethodAction` first.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{ 
    if(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
         if(overrideLinksSwitch.on == TRUE)
         {
             [self myMethodAction];
             [myWebView stopLoading];
             return YES;
         }
        else
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps...